How to generate random cracks effects?
So I'm making an abandoned building in Minecraft. And I need to make cracks in the floor and the effect of stripped wallpaper on the walls. So as the area of the building is large, I tried to automate the process of establishing cracks through the function of random.
I used:
//replace stone 80%stone,5%stone_stairs[facing=east],5%stone_stairs[facing=north],5%stone_stairs[facing=south],5%stone_stairs[facing=west],5%stone_slab

But the result is not what I wanted:

I wanted to get cracks like this:

So to the question. How can I make a crack pattern to cover the whole floor area? Are there any "conditions" in WorldEdit?
Also I need to make a texture for the walls like here (problem and question is the same as with the floor):

UPD:
okay, I realize that axiom is a better choice for this purpose.
